# MS Visual Studio C++

Tags: visual-studio, c++, visual-c++

Здравствуйте, я не давно начал работать в MS Visual studio C++ 6,0 и столкнулся с проблемой: я создал форму и в ней кнопку. Задача чтобы после нажатия кнопки появлялся текст.

Comment: Какого типа проект? Речь о MFC?

Comment: Интересная у вас проблема. Я думаю решение ее вы найдете почти в любой книги по программированию графических программ в Windows. 

[оффтоп]
//Извините, не удержался!
Я вчера скачал MASM, VS2010. Так же я купил книги по asm'у, Си, С++, низкоуровневому программированию, программированию драйверов, программированию ОС.
Задача: 
Написать ОС!
[/оффтоп]


Comment: В чем проблема?

Answer (score 4):

Почитайте учебник по MS Visual Studio C++. Хочется реально заниматься интересными вопросами, а не разжевывать азы. К тому же, Вы даже версию MSVS не указали и что за тип программу делаете.

Вкратце:

- добавить обработчик нажатия кнопки
- добавить текстовый элемент на форму, задать ему свойство hidden или типа того
- в обработчике отобразить текстовый элемент (изменить свойство или вызвать ф-цию - не помню точно, посмотрите в справке), перерисовать окно.